# css for two layouts (Front and Admin) not working in production mode

Tags: css, webpack, vuejs2, production, vue-cli

I'm new in vue js. I set up new vue project using vue cli and also choose template webpack.
My project has two parts : Frontend and Admin panel. Both have different templates.
So, i give route meta "backend" for all backend components.
I added all css by following logic in main.js

> ```
> if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.backend)) {
>    require('../static/backend.css')
>    next()
>   } else {
>     require('../static/frontend.css')
>     next()
>   }
> })
> ```

When i run "npm run dev" command , all css works perfectly, But when i run "npm run build" command, all css merged in one file. So my backend css override on frontend.

Please give me any solution for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see how to do it in single page mode, if you like to have js, css and html files:

Frontend.vue :

```
<style scoped  lang="css" src="../static/frontend.css"></style>
<template src='./frontend.html'></template>
<script src='./frontend.js'></script>
```

Backend.vue :

```
<style scoped  lang="css" src="../static/backend.css"></style>
<template src='./backend.html'></template>
<script src='./backend.js'></script>
```

but most of the time, css, template and js are inside the single page.

Then you can use vue-router or dynamic-async components to charge backend or frontend...

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/routing.html router
- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html dynamic-async

If you want to stick to your organization (which I don't know). With webpack4 you can chunk your js in separate files :

- https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

But I don't think it will be enough, you might need to use a promise to set the css dynamically :

```
() => import('./../static/backend.css')
```